# Accessing magento web services without authentication

Tags: php, magento

It's possible to access Magento web services without do authentication/login?

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/soap/api/?wsdl');

/* AVOID LOGIN $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); */

$result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method');
```

Comment: You still need the api user and api key so the session is limited to only what should be accessed. The last thing you want is unlimited access on the api under most situations.

Comment: I think the same but are customer requirements...